# Is it safe to call Block_copy() and Block_release() on nil?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks, null

Do I need to check or does it behave like `free()` and such where it will ignore `nil`?

I'm unable to find documentation that states clearly one way or the other.

My *suspicion* is that it is safe.  E.g., this...

```
(lldb) p (void)_Block_release(0)
<no result>
```

...didn't crash, it seems.  I think that's what that means?

Comment: You're right, the documentation doesn't state anything.

Comment: of course, it would be easier to just call `[... copy]` and `[... release]` on it -- that will *for sure* work with `nil`

Comment: Are those selectors documented?

Comment: @jeffamaphone: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#objective-c-extensions "Foundation defines (and supplies) -copy and -release methods for Blocks."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this:

```
Block_copy(-1);
```

This obviously caused a crash, so I stepped into the assembly code:

```
0x7fff9035342a:  movq   %rdi, %r15
0x7fff9035342d:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x7fff9035342f:  testq  %r15, %r15
0x7fff90353432:  je     0x7fff903535ca            ; _Block_copy_internal + 430
```

In rdi there should be the only argument pushed: the block address in this case.

It's content is stored in r15 and it's being compared before the conditional jump. And the address 0x7fff903535ca is at the end, when it starts to pop from the stack, so yes, it's nil safe:

```
0x7fff903535ca:  addq   $8, %rsp
0x7fff903535ce:  popq   %rbx
0x7fff903535cf:  popq   %r12
0x7fff903535d1:  popq   %r13
0x7fff903535d3:  popq   %r14
0x7fff903535d5:  popq   %r15
0x7fff903535d7:  popq   %rbp
0x7fff903535d8:  ret
```

Comment: Nice detective work.   But if it isn't documented, it isn't safe.  However, this might as well be a documentation bug given that it is likely a binary compatibility issue to change it now.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's safe, like free(), etc, but couldn't find any citation as evidence.

Are you trying to avoid the check or the clutter in code?  If the latter, we could add a macro that would make it so we don't care what the right answer is...

```
// Not sure if it's okay to Block_release nil
#define My_Block_release(b) ((b)? _Block_release(b) : 0)
```

Comment: Yes, mainly trying to avoid clutter.  I considered the macro solution as well.